# How to reflect relationship beween subclasses in XML

Tags: xsd, entity-relationship

How can i define relationship between subclasses in XML, for example a class researcher has two subclass Paper and author .

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would be using an XML schema to describe relationships in an XML file. But I seriously *doubt* you should make a model where researcher has *subclass* paper and author, it seems more like researcher is related to the class Paper in the role of Author. All of this you can describe in [XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml_schema).